# Set value in a new dataframe column based on some rule in existing column

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to create a new column in existing dataframe where the value in each row is conditional on some rule in adjacent column. Let me give an example. 
I have the following dictionary:

```
d1={"commence_time":["12/6/2019 14:00", "12/7/2019 17:30", 
                     "12/7/2019 17:30","12/8/2019 19:30",
                     "12/9/2019 19:30","12/28/2019 15:00",
                     "12/28/2019 15:00","12/28/2019 15:00"],
"value1":["5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5"]}
```

and I create the following DataFrame:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
```

which results in:

```
    commence_time     value1
 0  12/6/2019 14:00     5
 1  12/7/2019 17:30     5
 2  12/7/2019 17:30     5
 3  12/8/2019 19:30     5
 4  12/9/2019 19:30     5
 5  12/28/2019 15:00    5
 6  12/28/2019 15:00    5
 7  12/28/2019 15:00    5
```

I want to create another column called value2 where the following rule applies: If commence time is followed by different commence time in the next row, value2 in the first row should be equal to value1. If commence time is exactly the same as in the following row (or potentially even the subsequent row) then numbers in value2 are value1 summed by 5. Expected result is:

```
    commence_time   value1  value2
 0  12/6/2019 14:00    5      5
 1  12/7/2019 17:30    5     10
 2  12/7/2019 17:30    5     10
 3  12/8/2019 19:30    5      5
 4  12/9/2019 19:30    5      5
 5  12/28/2019 15:00   5     10
 6  12/28/2019 15:00   5     10
 7  12/28/2019 15:00   5     10
```

Don't really know how to approach this problem so I didn't really try anything. Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused about whether the values will always be the same, or what should happen if the last group were 5,6,6. Is the output supposed to be 11,12,12 or 11,11,12, or something different

Comment: In fact if the last group values were 5,6,6 then summing by 5 would give 10,11,11. The values in "value1" will not be always the same to answer the question. I input same value for simplicity and readability but I realize this may bring confusion in the context of the possible solutions.

Comment: What should happen in the last row of the dataframe?

Comment: If commence time is different than the one in preceding row then copy value from column "value1". If not (i.e. commence time is the same as in previous row) then value 2 summed up by 5.

Comment: By summed up by do you mean add 5 to those rows (and in general this could be some other number like 7.5234, that has no relationship to value1 in the DataFrame)?

Comment: Yes, adding up 5 to those rows. And yes the number doesn't have relation to value1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DataFrame appears sorted as above then this isn't so much a consecutive check as it could just be a `duplicated` check. Use the mask to add 5 to only the rows you want.

```
magic_num = 5

df1['value2'] = df1.value1.astype(int) + df1.commence_time.duplicated(keep=False)*magic_num
```

But if it truly needs to be a consecutive row check, not anywhere in the DataFrame, you can do this checking shifted values and finding groups that are larger than 1 to add the value to.

```
s = df1.commence_time.ne(df1.commence_time.shift()).cumsum()
df1['value2'] = df1.value1.astype(int) + (s.groupby(s).transform('size') > 1)*magic_num
```

---

```
      commence_time value1  value2
0   12/6/2019 14:00      5       5
1   12/7/2019 17:30      5      10
2   12/7/2019 17:30      5      10
3   12/8/2019 19:30      5       5
4   12/9/2019 19:30      5       5
5  12/28/2019 15:00      5      10
6  12/28/2019 15:00      5      10
7  12/28/2019 15:00      5      10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy
d1={"commence_time":["12/6/2019 14:00", "12/7/2019 17:30", 
                 "12/7/2019 17:30","12/8/2019 19:30",
                 "12/9/2019 19:30","12/28/2019 15:00",
                 "12/28/2019 15:00","12/28/2019 15:00"],
"value1":[5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]}


 df1=pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

 df1['timeshift']= df1.commence_time.shift(-1)
 df1['valueshift']= df1.value1.shift(-1)

 df1['value2'] = np.where(df1.commence_time == df1.timeshift,
                     df1.value1 + df1.valueshift,df1.value1)
```

Hi try that, you can look at the numpy docs for more info on np.where, my solution is probably a bit hacky, but I am sure someone will be along soon to improve it.

Comment: I converted you r "value1":["5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5"] to ints as I am presuming your are only using this as an example